# quantile function in R in a resampling form for Bootstrap

Tags: r, simulation, resampling

I am currently reading Efron's book "An  introduction to the Bootstrap" and I am focusing in the ABC confidence intervals section on chapter 14.Trying to implement this method I found that there exists a function in R from bootstrap package that implements it.

The following data are from the book page 180.

```
A = c(48,36,20,29,42,42,20,42,22,41,45,14,6,0,33,28,34,4,32,24,47,41,24,26,30,41)
```

The mean of the data is :

```
mean(A)
[1] 29.65385
```

Now the bootstrap package abcnon function web page is [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bootstrap/versions/2019.6/topics/abcnon)
that has a toy example.

Both the book and the help of the function say that the theta function must be written in a resampling form.

For example the sum is written as :

```
theta <- function(p,x) {sum(p*x)/sum(p)}
```

Which if I find the 0.5 quantile is true:

```
results <- bootstrap::abcnon(A, theta,alpha=0.5)  
results$limits
     alpha      abc     stan
[1,]   0.5 29.60023 29.65385
```

Now let's say that instead of the mean I want theta to be the quantile function.How can I write it in this resampling form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ABC method is not applicable to quantiles. The second paragraph of Section 14.4 *The ABC method* explains:

> The ABC method (...) requires that the statistic theta_hat = s(x) is defined smoothly in x. An example of an unsmooth statistic is the sample median.

The median is the 50% quantile. Quantiles are not smooth functions.

Comment: The BCA method can be calculated for quantile thought.Right ?

Comment: Yes but the *theta* function is trivial. It's just *quantile* with *prob* equal to the quantile you have in mind.